# Visual-C++ inline assembler difference of two offsets

Tags: c, windows, x86, inline-assembly

I'm porting chunk of code from MASM to C inline assembler (x86, Windows, MS VC)
Foolowing is not a real code, just spoof to give an idea. Let's say I have some data defined as static array or even a code chunk between two labels, and I need to get size of it.

```
    label1:
    bla bla bla
    label2:
    ....
    mov eax, (offset label2 - offset label1)
```

Such a code works in MASM like a charm, but in C I get following error message:
"error C2425: '-' : non-constant expression in 'second operand'"
I can get compiled:

```
    mov eax, offset label1
    mov eax, offset label2
```

I expect compiler to evaluate (offset label1 - offset label2) at compile time, but it looks like I'm wrong. I can't add offsets as well (why? these are just two integers added during compilation...?)
Sure, I can get
        mov eax, offset label2
        mov edx, offset label1
        sub eax, edx
compiled, but that's an extra code just for calculating a constant.
Can someone explain me please, what is wrong in my code?

Can it be something caused by relocation? How to push it through?

Looking forward to an answer,
thank you.

Comment: You can at least simplify it a bit: mov eax, offset label2; sub eax, offset label1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be caused by the threat of relocation but also threat of variable length instructions dealing with relative jumps. Most likely because of some minor trouble, the assembler writers took the easy way out and implemented a 1 pass or a two pass compiler that makes final decisions as soon as possible. And thus some convenient expressions are unsupported.

As already suggested in the comment, the assembler still probably supports mov + sub combination.

Answer (score 0):

The real assembler is probably running over the code in several passes before it has gotten fixed addresses for all the labels. For example, some jumps have a short and a long form depending on how far you want to jump. If you have such a jump between the labels, the distance depends on where the jump is going to.

The C compiler might leave some of that to the linker/loader and not have the values fixed at compile time.

You could very well get the addres calculation code down to two instructions

```
mov EAX, offset Label2
sub EAX, offset Label1
```

I don't think this will exactly ruin the performance of the code.

Comment: Well... if it doesn't know that when compiling this __asm block, how does it know offset of label2 then? Seems like it does; then theres' no difference whether I ask it to sub at compile time, or do it myself with sub eax, offset label1.

Comment: Problem is that in real code such a calculation is needed for lea eax, [ebx + ()] and I don't have free registers and so on. I guess there is some limitation in compilator so that it can't evaluate such expressions. Thank you for reply!

Comment: The compiler might not know the exact address, but the linker or program loader will fill in the blanks later.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thank you very much. Bad news actually since I have to rewrite this chunk now.